# UIAlertController reuse more times with NSObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsobject

In my app, UIAlertController uses much time.So, I create `NSObject` **Helper**.

Here is Helper.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "PrefixHeader.pch"
#import "LectureViewController.h"

@interface Helper : NSObject
+(void) showNotice:(NSString *) message;
+(void) showNoticeWithAction;
@end
```

Here is Helper.m

```
#import "Helper.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation Helper


+(void) showNotice:(NSString *) message{
    NSArray *versionArray = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
    if ([[versionArray objectAtIndex:0] intValue] >= 9) {

        //ver.IOS >= 9
        UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil
                                                                       message:message
                                                                preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        alert.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
//        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

            }];

        });

    } else {
        //ver.IOS < 9
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert performSelector:@selector(show) withObject:nil afterDelay:5];
    }

}

@end
```

This line cant run in Helper: `[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];` because of `presentViewController`. Please help me

Comment: You meant you need to show it from helper but you don't have viewcontroller to present?

Comment: Yes, it's. I dont have solution for it. I'm newbie

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting this error because the base class is NSObject and `self` represent the object of that class and NSObject does'nt have any method named presentViewController.

To resolve it you need to pass an object of UIViewController in that method and on that object use presentViewController like this

```
+(void) showNotice:(NSString *) message andViewController : (UIViewController *) controller;
```

And use it like this

```
 [controller presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

the batter way create c function in @end of the class nsobject

```
void showAlertView( NSString *title,NSString *message) {
    [[[UIAlertController alloc]initWithTitle:title message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil] show];
}
```

and call in any class like this

```
showAlertView(@"Done", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",responseObject[@"message"]]);
```

Comment: I have  `UIAlertView` and `UIAlertController`.
`UIAlertView` not use to over ios 9.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this while your controller is pushed and presented .

```
 UIViewController *vc = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
 [[vc presentedViewController] ? vc.presentedViewController : vc presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```